# How to find an element in an array that corresponds to the second array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, interpolation

I have two 1D arrays:

```
x  y
0  5
2  10
4  15
6  20
8  25
10 30
```

I would like to find the value of `y` at given `x`. But the element is not in the array but instead the value of the element is in between these elements. For example, I want to find the value of `y` when `x = 2.5` or `x = 5`. I should probably use the interpolate function, but I am finding it very confusing.

Comment: what, *exactly* do you have? Are you working with lists? Or Numpy arrays? Is that what you mean by "the interpolate function"? Please always provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To interpolate between values, I would suggest using `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
f = interp1d(x, y)
```

This creates a function `f` where you can pass values into and it will return the interpolated value. i.e. `f(3)` will output `12.5`.

Comment: Thank you, kind sir. @Tom McLean